# How do I change the color of percentage label to be white in pie chart without interfering the text label color?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, pie-chart

How do I change the color of percentage label to be white in pie chart without interfering the text label color using matplotlib? When I edit  `textprops={'size': 'x-large','color':'w'}`, the text color will turn white which it is not contrast to the background.

```
labels = df01['new_sentiment']
count = df01['count']

cmap = plt.get_cmap('Greys')
colors = list(cmap(np.linspace(0.45, 0.85, len(count))))

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.pie(count, labels=labels, autopct='%1.1f%%', textprops={'size': 'x-large'}, colors=colors)

ax1.axis('equal')
plt.title('7D-prior-PM_sem_sen', pad=30)
plt.savefig('04_7D-prior-PM_sem_sen.tiff', dpi=300, format='tiff', bbox_inches='tight')
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the colors of the inner labels like this:

```
_,_,m = ax1.pie(count, labels=labels, autopct='%1.1f%%', textprops={'size': 'x-large'}, colors=colors)
[m[i].set_color('white') for i in range(len(m))]
```